# Linux - Password as script arguments and autoinput

Tags: linux

I'm trying to execute a Linux shell script through my java program and i'd like my script to take as argument the root's password. As my Linux knowledge goes i know that if i make the command `sudo apt-get update -y` he updates everything without prompting me for confirmation.

Is there any way to make the same but with the password? Whenever the script prompts for password he automatically reads the argument and inputs it?

EDIT: If i create a script to execute my jar file with sudo (ex: sudo javac -jar /mnt/raid/program.jar), do my scripts called upon get sudo rights aswell? As of an inheritance.

Comment: if you run your program from sudo, it runs as root with whatever privileges uid 0 has (root doesn't need to use sudo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sudo has the -S argument. From the sudo man page:

```
 The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from
 the standard input instead of the terminal device. The password
 must be followed by a new-line character.
```

You could do something like:

```
echo PASSWORD | sudo -S COMMAND
```

Comment: The problem is that now the system tells me: "user is not in the sudoers file, this incident will be reported". I'm using the following: echo Passw0rd | sudo -S echo "Hey" > /mnt/raid/file

Comment: @Ângelo: "user is not in the sudoers file" is exactly what it means, it's probably not executing as the user you think it is. Your example here is also broken if the original user can't write to `/mnt/raid/file`, the redirection happens before sudo is executed.

Comment: My bad mate.. You were absolutely correct. Tested this in a real machine instead of a VM and it worked. Thumbs up for the answer, thank you.